# Can't getting total when a product has discount price

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get total amount. Like when a product has discount price the total will be discount_price * quantity = total

For that i have this model and view:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product")
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    discount_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(datetime.datetime.today, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_S, blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    payment_method = models.ForeignKey(PaymentMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    total = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.discount_price:
            self.total = self.discount_price * self.quantity
        else:
            self.total = self.price * self.quantity
        return super().save(self, *args, **kwargs)


class Checkout(View):
    def post(self, request):
        fname = request.POST.get("fname")
        phone = request.POST.get("phone")
        address = request.POST.get("address")
        cart = request.session.get("cart")
        customer = request.session.get("customer")
        products = Product.get_products_id(list(cart.keys()))

        for product in products:
            if discount_price:
                order = Order(
                    customer=Customer(id=customer["id"]),
                    product=product,
                    fname=fname,
                    discount_price=product.discount_price,
                    phone=phone,
                    address=address,
                    quantity=cart.get(str(product.id)),
                )
            else:
                order = Order(
                    customer=Customer(id=customer["id"]),
                    product=product,
                    fname=fname,
                    price=product.price,
                    phone=phone,
                    address=address,
                    quantity=cart.get(str(product.id)),
                )

            order.save()

        request.session["cart"] = {}

        return redirect("cart")
```

Comment: What does "not working as I want" mean? Do you receive an error? The wrong output? No output? Something else? Please update your question so as to reflect the actual problem.

Comment: no error total doesnt change when a product has discount price it doesnt change

Comment: Don't use `FloatField`s for your prices if you want your accounting to be correct. Floating-point numbers are imprecise.

Comment: As a second aside: shouldn't each product in a single order be represented as an "order line", instead of each product getting its own order?

Answer (score 0):

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.discount_price:
            self.total = self.discount_price * self.quantity
        else:
            self.total = self.price * self.quantity
        super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

try this in your model